# What is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with the following generating sets.

Tags: measure-theory

Question: What is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{C}=\{3\mathbb{Z},4\mathbb{Z}\}$, where the ambient space is $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What is the topology that you are taking on $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @AhmedHussein I dunno to be honest. This is an exercise from Probability Path by Resnick. I think he just means the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathcal{C}=\{3\mathbb{Z},4\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: @Mathemagician You are right. And that is why Resnick does **not** use the word "Borel" in this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The Borel  $\sigma$-algebra, generated by $3Z,4Z$,  is   $\{ A: A$ is presented  as  a union of any  subfamily of the family  $\{  3Z\setminus 4Z, 4Z \setminus 3Z, 4Z \cap 3Z, Z \setminus (3Z \cup 4Z)\} \}$ . ( We assume $\emptyset$ is subfamily of that  family.

Comment: can you explain how you arrived at this conclusion? I don't know how to start with.

Comment: @Gogi Your list is missing several sets, like $3Z$ for example. The $\sigma$-field actually has 16 sets in it.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland   $3Z= (3Z\setminus 4Z) \cup (4Z \cap 3Z)$

Comment: @Gogi Yes, and this set is not included in your list.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland   $3Z= (3Z\setminus 4Z) \cup (4Z \cap 3Z)$.  You are  rigth, I have indicated  the Borel $\sigma$ -algebra uncorectly.   the Borel $\sigma$ -algebra  is  $\{ A: A$ is presented  as  a union of any  subfamily of the family  $\{  3Z\setminus 4Z, 4Z \setminus 3Z, 4Z \cap 3Z, Z \setminus (3Z \cup 4Z)\}$ . ( We assume $\emptyset$ is subfamily of that  family.